# sql query to get word between characters

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have problem where I have a string and I need to get a specific part of it.

For example:

```
    \Stack\Over\Programming\Users\
```

I need "Programming" from the above string.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @TExt NVARCHAR(MAX)= '\Stack\Over\Programming\Users\'

    DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(1000)= '\' ;
    WITH    numbers
              AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY o.object_id, o2.object_id ) Number
                   FROM     sys.objects o
                            CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
                 ),
            c AS ( SELECT   Number CHARBegin ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY number ) RN
                   FROM     numbers
                   WHERE    SUBSTRING(@text, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
                 ),
            res
              AS ( SELECT   CHARBegin ,
                            CAST(LEFT(@text, charbegin) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) Res ,
                            RN
                   FROM     c
                   WHERE    rn = 1
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   c.CHARBegin ,
                            CAST(SUBSTRING(@text, res.CHARBegin+1,
                                           c.CHARBegin - res.CHARBegin-1) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) ,
                            c.RN
                   FROM     c
                            JOIN res ON c.RN = res.RN + 1
                 )
        SELECT  *
        FROM    res
```

**Result:**

```
CHARBegin   |Res         |RN
1           | \         |1
7           |Stack      |2
12         |Over        |3
24         |Programming |4
30         |Users       |5
```

In your case you need last statement

```
SELECT  *  FROM    res WHERE Rn=4
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the word between the 3th and 4th `\`, following would do the trick.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(32)
SET @String = '\Stack\Over\Programming\Users\'

SELECT SUBSTRING(
        @String
        , CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
        , CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, 1) + 1) + 1) + 1)
          - CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, CHARINDEX('\', @String, 1) + 1) + 1) - 1)
```

Comment: @Lieven..Thanks a lot.This is exactly i wanted

Comment: @ramesh - no problem but the solution Dalex provided has a much better coolness factor.

Comment: Could also use `PARSENAME(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@String,2,len(@String)-2),'\','.'),2)` for added coolness (but less robustness!)

Comment: @Martin, why don't you make an answer out of it, you'll have my vote. Much more readable and only *robustness* decrease I can think of is the possibility of additional '.' characters.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create a string split function in SQL. unfortunately there is not one built into MS SQL.

[How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)